# How to edit a success notification message in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, notification

1. How to edit checkout/cart/configure/id/397514/ page success notification message in Magento 1.9 and project file location?
2. How to custom [object object] message?

   [image]

Comment: I think you have customised it. Please update the customised file and location.

Comment: Please provide more details so it can be easier for everyone to understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, there is a simple way to accomplish this using translation files.

1. Navigate to app/locale/en_US folder (or whichever language you want to edit)
2. Select and edit Mage_Checkout.csv.
3. look for something like this:
   %s was added to your shopping cart.,%s was added to your shopping cart.
4. Now, change the line after the comma to what you would like it to be:

> %s was added to your shopping cart., You can translate it here!

5. Save the file and clear the cache, you would notice it changed.